# Angular Material: How to hide input field based on checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a checkbox cbAddVestingOption that, when checked, should display an input field.

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 600px">
                  <mat-checkbox [formcontrolname]="cbAddVestingOption" style="padding-bottom: 200px;">Add Vesting Option</mat-checkbox>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Vesting Option" matInput formcontrolname="vestedoption" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class="uppercase" />
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of vestedOptions" [value]="option">
                      {{option}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
                </mat-form-field>
```

So when cbAddVestingOption is checked, vestedoption should display. When cbAddVestingOption is not c hecked, vestedoption should be hidden.

Do I need to do this in the typescript or can I do it in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly on the template like this:

```
  <mat-checkbox #checkbox>Add Vesting Option</mat-checkbox>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Vesting Option" matInput [hidden]="!checkbox.checked"/>
```

ADDED: A better option, using `*ngIf` on the whole `<mat-form-field>`:

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox>Add Vesting Option</mat-checkbox>
<mat-form-field *ngIf="checkbox.checked" style="width: 600px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Vesting Option" matInput formControlName="vestedoption" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
```

Comment: It didn't work. When I click the checkbox, the input is still there.

Comment: It still shows the bar that the autocomplete gives but the text does get hidden.

Comment: Yes, they are different elements, but you can use plain css for that. As another option, you can take the checkbox out of the `<mat-form-field>` and use `*ngIf` or css on it, see my updated answer.